# Why can not I access network timing data without Timing-Allow-Origin in resource timing API

Tags: html, performance, resource-timing-api

I am reading this post about [resource timing API](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-resource-timing-api) and I can not understand the reason behind the following restriction:

> Resources fetched from a third-party must provide an additional HTTP
>   header (Timing-Allow-Origin: *) to allow the site to gather detailed
>   network timing data. If the header is absent, the only available data
>   is the total duration of the request.

While I can easily understand the reason behind blocking requests without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, I am struggling to understand why should not I get information about timing without `Timing-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading [W3C document about resource timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/) I found that they give an explanation for this in [privacy & security section](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/#privacy-security)

> Statistical fingerprinting is a privacy concern where a malicious web
>   site may determine whether a user has visited a third-party web site
>   by measuring the timing of cache hits and misses of resources in the
>   third-party web site. Though the PerformanceResourceTiming interface
>   gives timing information for resources in a document, the cross-origin
>   restrictions prevent making this privacy concern any worse than it is
>   today using the load event on resources to measure timing to determine
>   cache hits and misses.

Basically they want to prevent malicious people from checking whether a user accessed some page previously.